# Using a nested type parameter as a toplevel type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

The following generic type contains the type parameter `A` two times:

```
class Something<B<A>, A>
```

I wonder if it would be possible to write only `class Something<B<A>>` because `A` is already given through `B<A>`.

I think it is not possible, but maybe I've overlooked something.

Comment: I don't think the compiler can infer this.  It is not the same as generic method inferance.

Comment: FYI: "maybe I've _overlooked_ something", [Oversee defined](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+oversee&aq=f&oq=define%3A+oversee&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Overlook defined](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+overlook&aq=f&oq=define%3A+overlook&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Hope this helps.

Comment: If you need the type parameter `A` within the class `Something`, you'll have to leave it as two type parameters as the type parameter to `B` will be unavailable to `Something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question officially: The compiler cannot infer the type this way.