# Using nested type parameter without declaring it twice in TS

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430701/using-a-nested-type-parameter-as-a-toplevel-type-parameter) in TypeScript?

If not, is there a formal explanation as to why the compiler can't infer nested type parameters?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```ts
interface TestFilter {
    name?: string;
}

interface FilterComponent<F> {
    setFilter(filter: F)
}

class TestFilterComponent implements FilterComponent<TestFilter> {
    private filter: TestFilter;

    setFilter(filter: TestFilter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
}

// Can I use F without declaring it as another type parameter?
// Something like: class FilterWrapperComponent<FC extends FilterComponent<F>>
abstract class FilterWrapperComponent<F, FC extends FilterComponent<F>> {
    private sidebarFilter: FC;
    private modalFilter: FC;

    public passFilter(filter: F) {
        this.sidebarFilter.setFilter(filter);
        this.modalFilter.setFilter(filter);
    }
}

// I want to just write "extends FilterWrapperComponent<TestFilterComponent>"
// and get TestFilter as F automatically
class TestFilterWrapperComponent extends FilterWrapperComponent<TestFilter, TestFilterComponent> {

}
```

Also available on [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20TestFilter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FilterComponent%3CF%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setFilter(filter%3A%20F)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestFilterComponent%20implements%20FilterComponent%3CTestFilter%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20filter%3A%20TestFilter%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setFilter(filter%3A%20TestFilter)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.filter%20%3D%20filter%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Can%20I%20use%20F%20without%20declaring%20it%20as%20another%20type%20parameter%3F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Something%20like%3A%20class%20FilterWrapperComponent%3CFC%20extends%20FilterComponent%3CF%3E%3E%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20FilterWrapperComponent%3CF%2C%20FC%20extends%20FilterComponent%3CF%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20sidebarFilter%3A%20FC%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20modalFilter%3A%20FC%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20passFilter(filter%3A%20F)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.sidebarFilter.setFilter(filter)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.modalFilter.setFilter(filter)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20want%20to%20just%20write%20%22extends%20FilterWrapperComponent%3CTestFilterComponent%3E%22%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20get%20TestFilter%20as%20F%20automatically%0D%0Aclass%20TestFilterWrapperComponent%20extends%20FilterWrapperComponent%3CTestFilter%2C%20TestFilterComponent%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Please, provide all necessary details in the question itself, this will help the readers to understand the question. Also, no, it's not possible, and your example differs from this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430701/using-a-nested-type-parameter-as-a-toplevel-type-parameter , because `TestFilterComponent` is not `FilterComponent<TestFilter>`, it just implements it but it's separate class/interface.

Comment: @estus Updated the question. As for "just implements the interface", I can replace it with abstract class to get "is-a" relationship and but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, generic parameter value is `{}`. It applies when a parameter is omitted. It's possible to change default value with with [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).

> I want to just write "extends FilterWrapperComponent"
>   and get TestFilter as F automatically

This is possible in the opposite way, to get both `FilterComponent<TestFilter>` and `TestFilter` by specifying only `TestFilter`:

```
abstract class FilterWrapperComponent<F, FC = FilterComponent<F>> {}

class TestFilterWrapperComponent extends FilterWrapperComponent<TestFilter> {}
```

Comment: Almost what I wanted. The only difference is that I get `FilterComponent<TestFilter>` so I can't use methods from `TestFilterComponent` that don't belong to the interface.

Comment: In your example, all methods (setFilter) are shared. If TestFilterComponent has methods that FilterComponent doesn't then this is exactly the problem that I mentioned, above, *TestFilterComponent is not FilterComponent<TestFilter>, it just implements it but it's separate class/interface*. It isn't related to this question in this case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430701/using-a-nested-type-parameter-as-a-toplevel-type-parameter .

Comment: I.e. there is no direct relationship between TestFilterComponent and TestFilter anymore, because TestFilterComponent isn't generic class. This is exactly what param default serves for. If you need only methods from FilterComponent<TestFilter>, you can omit second param. If you need something special (TestFilterComponent or any other compatible type), second param should be specified.

Comment: Right, I didn't add TFC-specific methods to the example. I see, I can either start from filter and be limited by interface for FilterComponent or I can use the implementation of FilterComponent but can't get the filter type automatically.

Answer (score 2):

With the `infer` statement, you can infer types [inside conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).

That means you can extract types "hidden" in another type.
Next, I wrote `UnwrapFilter` which extracts the `Filter` generic argument from a `FilterComponent` type.

```js
type UnwrapFilter<T extends FilterComponent<any>> = T extends FilterComponent<infer TC> ? TC : never;

abstract class FilterWrapperComponent2<FC extends FilterComponent<any>> {
    constructor(
      private sidebarFilter: FC,
      private modalFilter: FC,
    ) {}

    public passFilter(filter: UnwrapFilter<FC>) {
        this.sidebarFilter.setFilter(filter);
        this.modalFilter.setFilter(filter);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if a more general version - not relying on the specific `FilterComponent` type - of `UnwrapFilter` can be written.
That is because the `infer` statement seems to require `T` to be a direct instantiation of whatever comes after `extends`, i.e. in the following example `T1` is properly inferred, but `T2` isn't.

```js
interface OneParamGeneric<T> {}
type UnwrapOneParam<T extends OneParamGeneric<{}>> = T extends OneParamGeneric<infer TypeArg> ? TypeArg : never;

type T1 = UnwrapOneParam<OneParamGeneric<TestFilter>>;
type T2 = UnwrapOneParam<FilterComponent<TestFilter>>;
```

---

In other scenarios a *type query* - now referred to in the documentation as [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) - may be used.

In this example, `PublicFilterComponent` exposes the `activeFilter` as a field, thereby allowing access via the square bracket syntax `PublicFilterComponent['activeFilter']`.

```js
interface PublicFilterComponent<F> {
    public readonly activeFilter: F;
    setFilter(filter: F): void;
}


abstract class FilterWrapperComponent3<FC extends PublicFilterComponent<any>> {
    constructor(
      private sidebarFilter: FC,
      private modalFilter: FC,
    ) {}

    public passFilter(filter: FC['activeFilter']) {
        this.sidebarFilter.setFilter(filter);
        this.modalFilter.setFilter(filter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can in TypeScript 2.8 which is currently in release candidate state and available by installing `typescript@rc`.

TypeScript 2.8 comes with conditional types and type inference for conditional types. What you actually want is type inference in the generic constraint but that's not directly possible, the workaround is to use a conditional type which resolves to `never` in the else branch.

```
interface FilterComponent<F = any> {
    setFilter(filter: F)
}

type ExtractFilter<C extends FilterComponent> = C['setFilter'] extends (filter: infer F) => void ? F : never;
```

Now you can write your classes like this:

```
abstract class FilterWrapperComponent<FC extends FilterComponent> {
    private sidebarFilter: FC;
    private modalFilter: FC;

    public passFilter(filter: ExtractFilter<FC>) {
        this.sidebarFilter.setFilter(filter);
        this.modalFilter.setFilter(filter);
    }
}

class TestFilterWrapperComponent extends FilterWrapperComponent<TestFilterComponent> {
}
```

Comment: Looks hacky though. What if I change the `setFilter` method name? I wonder why didn't they make it less cumbersome (even though it's workaround, it shows that compiler can get the type somehow).

Comment: Of course, it'd be much nicer to write `class FilterWrapper<FC extends FilterComponent<infer F>>`, but [according to Anders Hejlsberg](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496#issuecomment-362861100) "it is not trivial to implement", he's not giving specifics why though. My answer is based on the workaround he proposed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I couldn't find any info in TS docs/developer comments for this.